# reflect.TypeOf is *string and returns 0xc0001ae4a8 - how to print

Tags: go

This is my code from retrieving results from the Go AWS client:

```
  fmt.Println("Success", reflect.TypeOf(result.Reservations[0].Instances[0].Architecture))
  Success *string

fmt.Println("Success", result.Reservations[0].Instances[0].Architecture)
Success 0xc0001ae4a8
```

I don't know why this is happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`result.Reservations[0].Instances[0].Architecture` is a pointer to a string.  The type prints as `*string`.  The value prints as hex.

If your goal is to print the value of the string, then [dereference](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Address_operators) the pointer:

```
fmt.Println("Success", *result.Reservations[0].Instances[0].Architecture)
```